# Laravel get all posts that a user commented on

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 Model named `User` , `Post` , `Comment` and this models are related.

**User Model :** This model has many Post model.

**Post Model :** This model belongs to User model and has many Comment model.

**Comment Model :** This model belongs to Post model and User model.

Now the question is how can i get all posts that a user commented on?

Comment: Look into the `whereHas` functionality.

Comment: @ceejayoz i want posts... whereHas is not helping in this case

Comment: Sure it will. It'll be something like `Post::whereHas('comment', function($query) use($user) { $query->whereUserId($user->id); });`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) is what you're looking for:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comment', function($query) use($user) {
    $query->whereUserId($user->id);
})->get();
```

`$user` would be the user you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

add to user

```
function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

and

```
User::find(1)->comments->map(function ($comment) { return $comment->post; })->unique();
```