# Laravel get all user who comment on post via post

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Ive been trying to get all user who commented on post

```
$post->comments()->user() //does not work
$post->comments()->load('user', function($q) { $q->select('email'); }));//does not work
$post->comments()->with('user')->get() //worked but not getting the user as result (still need to loop)
```

but im getting a BadMethodCallException
this are the models

```
//Comment Model
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
public function post(){
 return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}


//User Model
public function comments(){
     return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
public function posts(){
     return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

//Post Model
public function user(){
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
public function comments(){
     return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer (i think this is a duplicate question, but anyway)

[Laravel get all posts that a user commented on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49160825/laravel-get-all-posts-that-a-user-commented-on)

Instead i use this

```
$post->whereHas('comments', function($query) use($user) {
     $query->where('id',$user->id);
 })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try getting all comments belongs to that post with their users:

```
$users= Comment::where('post_id', $post->id)->with('user')->pluck('user');
```